# Getting deserialized values

Tags: c#, deserialization

I have deserialized an xml file which contains a list of programs, days, times and a true or false value against them. The file looks similar to below.

```
<AlarmSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ProgramSettings>
    <ProgramSetting>
      <ProgramPathText>Alarm.exe</ProgramPathText>
      <ProgramPathValue>D:\Documents\Work\Visual Studio\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\Alarm.exe</ProgramPathValue>
      <Monday>
        <Time>11:08</Time>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      </Monday>
      <Tuesday>
        <Time>17:08</Time>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      </Tuesday> 
    </ProgramSetting>
  </ProgramSettings>
</AlarmSettings>
```

I am trying to access the values but i keep getting stuck at the end of program settings where i cant see any methods that will be useful. I am needing to get to return the programpathtext values, programpathvalue values etc.

```
public void load()
{
     AlarmSettings alarmSettings;
     alarmSettings = AlarmSettings.Load(@"C:\Users\jason\Desktop\Booya.txt");

     alarmSettings.ProgramSettings.
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

AlarmSettings Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
namespace WindowsAlarm
{
    public class AlarmSettings
    {
        public List<ProgramSetting> ProgramSettings = new List<ProgramSetting>();


        public void Save(string filename)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AlarmSettings));
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);


            serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
            writer.Close();
        }

        public static AlarmSettings Load(string filename)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AlarmSettings));
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
                {
                    AlarmSettings loadedSettings = (AlarmSettings)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

                    reader.Close();

                    return loadedSettings;

                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
                //return new AlarmSettings();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `AlarmSettings` in you code?

Comment: Please post your definition of AlarmSettings as well

Comment: How have you deserialized? It would be helpful to show your deserialization code.

Comment: AlarmSettings is the name of my class. I have just put the deserialized code onto my post @vengets

Comment: So what is your question exactly??

Comment: @RoyDictus i cant access my values, for example, i cannot get into ProgramSetting and ProgramPathText etc.

Sorry if the question is abit confusing

Comment: Post your AlarmSettings class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. the problem was that i was not going in and accessing the collection.

```
        public void load()
    {
        AlarmSettings alarmSettings;
        alarmSettings = AlarmSettings.Load(@"C:\Users\jason\Desktop\Booya.txt");

        foreach (var setting in alarmSettings.ProgramSettings)
        {
            string pathtext = setting.ProgramPathText;
            string pathvalue = setting.ProgramPathValue;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have proper object structure , make use of XmlSerializer

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(objecttype));
```

or make use of Linq to XML or create you own XML parser for that you can serach on google

you can also check post which talks about serialization : [Object to XML using LINQ or XmlSerializer](http://pranayamr.blogspot.no/2013/03/object-to-xml-using-linq-or.html)

Comment: This option is the best in my opinion.

Comment: the AlarmSettings.Load goes of a deserialize's it and returns the values to alarmsettings.

Comment: @Jason - i m not getting what is issue now

Comment: @PranayRana i cant access my values, for example, i cannot get into ProgramSetting and ProgramPathText etc.

Comment: @Jason = i hope you have proper heirachy define in code ..if it like that than you code will be AlarmSettings.ProgramSetting to get access to other objects